# How to redirect a query string to a "virtual" subdirectory

Tags: wp-query, redirect, query-variable

Is it possible to redirect:

example.com/?language=en to example.com/en/

and

example.com/page/?language=en to example.com/en/page/

If so, how would it be accomplished?

Comment: Are you using any plugin for multi-language?

Comment: I am not.  This site is only going to have two languages, and I am interested in how to accomplish this sort of thing.

Comment: Can you please check in Settings >> Permalinks

Comment: Check what specifically?